# inserting special border to tikz mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, mindmaps

Hi I would like to mark certain nodes of tikz-mindmap just an example is illustrated in the figure.

Thanks in advance[image]

The minimal working code is here

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{CIR}{RGB}{255,0,35}
\definecolor{PN}{RGB}{97,189,64}
\definecolor{CFO}{RGB}{92,219,101}
\definecolor{DCO}{RGB}{255,131,211}
\definecolor{AN}{RGB}{72,163,235}
\definecolor{IQ}{RGB}{234,193,137} %253,224,158
\definecolor{IQTx}{RGB}{255,173,45} %241,88,21
\definecolor{IQRx}{RGB}{216,182,145}
\definecolor{IQFs}{RGB}{252,221,153}%206,165,75
\definecolor{IQFi}{RGB}{252,218,23}
\definecolor{baige}{RGB}{226,230,156}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, scale=0.8,
 every node/.style={scale=0.8},
 decoration={start radius=1cm, end radius=.15cm,amplitude=2mm,angle=30},
 outer sep=1pt
  ]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=red,text=white]
    node[concept] {\bf Root}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=IQ] {
      node[concept] {\textcolor{white}{\bf A}}
      [clockwise from=120]
      child [concept color=IQTx,text=white] { node[concept] {{\bf A1}} }
      child [concept color=IQRx,text=white] { node[concept] {{\bf A2} }  }
      child [concept color=IQFs,text=white] { node[concept] {{\bf A3} }  }
      child [concept color=IQFi,text=white]{ node[concept] {\bf A4} }
      }  
        child[concept color=DCO, grow=75, level distance=4.5cm,text=white ] {node[concept] {\bf B} }
child[concept color=PN, grow=150,level distance=4.5cm,text=white] { node[concept] {\bf C} } 
child[concept color=CFO, grow=215, level distance=4.5cm,text=white] { node[concept] {\bf D} }
child[concept color=AN, grow=290, level distance=4.5cm,text=white] { node[concept] {\bf E} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Mindmap Problem}
\label{fig:mindmap}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Any help would be much appreciated.

Muhammad Ali

Comment: To the person who downvoted this: Please make sure that you give the person who's asking a question a chance to improve their post, by leaving a comment explaining why you downvoted and how you think the question can be improved. Please also don't forget to come back and revert the down vote once the question has been improved. Finally, please note that on this site, down votes are typically reserved for exceptionally bad questions (i.e. spam).

Comment: Just a suggestion because I don't know nothing about TiKZ mindmaps so I don't know if it has sense but you could try to draw a similar mindmap with larger concepts (the ones with border) on background layer.

Answer (score 5):

Next code shows a possibility. It consists in drawing a bigger mindmap on `background` layer. In this case it has been easy because you already used `every node/.style={scale=0.8}`, so changing it to `scale=0.85` everything grown up. `Concepts` with border are drawn in black (or whatever color you prefer for border) and the other ones are drawn in white (or whatever color you use for your background).

I admit it's not the best solution, but it works.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{PN}{RGB}{97,189,64}
\definecolor{CFO}{RGB}{92,219,101}
\definecolor{DCO}{RGB}{255,131,211}
\definecolor{AN}{RGB}{72,163,235}
\definecolor{IQ}{RGB}{234,193,137} 
\definecolor{IQTx}{RGB}{255,173,45} 
\definecolor{IQRx}{RGB}{216,182,145}
\definecolor{IQFs}{RGB}{252,221,153}
\definecolor{IQFi}{RGB}{252,218,23}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, scale=0.8,
 every node/.style={scale=0.8},
 outer sep=1pt
  ]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=red,text=white]
    node[concept] {\bf Root}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=IQ] {
      node[concept] {\textcolor{white}{\bf A}}
      [clockwise from=120]
      child [concept color=IQTx,text=white] {node[concept] {{\bf A1}}}
      child [concept color=IQRx,text=white] {node[concept] {{\bf A2}}}
      child [concept color=IQFs,text=white] {node[concept] {{\bf A3}}}
      child [concept color=IQFi,text=white] {node[concept] {\bf A4}}
      }  
    child [concept color=DCO, grow=75, level distance=4.5cm, text=white] 
          {node[concept] {\bf B}}
    child [concept color=PN, grow=150, level distance=4.5cm, text=white] 
          {node[concept] {\bf C}} 
    child [concept color=CFO, grow=215, level distance=4.5cm, text=white] 
          {node[concept] {\bf D}}
    child [concept color=AN, grow=290, level distance=4.5cm, text=white] 
          {node[concept] {\bf E}};

\begin{scope}[on background layer, every node/.style={scale=.85}]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=black]
    node[concept] {\bf Root}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=black] {
      node[concept] {\textcolor{white}{\bf A}}
      [clockwise from=120]
      child [concept color=black,text=black] {node[concept] {{\bf A1}}}
      child [concept color=black,text=black] {node[concept] {{\bf A2}}}
      child [concept color=white,text=white] {node[concept] {{\bf A3}}}
      child [concept color=black,text=black] {node[concept] {\bf A4}}
      }  
      child [concept color=white, grow=75, level distance=4.5cm, text=white] 
            {node[concept] {\bf B}}
      child [concept color=white, grow=150, level distance=4.5cm, text=white] 
            {node[concept] {\bf C}} 
      child [concept color=black, grow=215, level distance=4.5cm, text=black] 
            {node[concept] {\bf D}}
      child [concept color=white, grow=290, level distance=4.5cm, text=white] 
            {node[concept] {\bf E}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

A simpler solution consists in adding a `general shadow` (or a `preaction`) to highlighted concepts. I don't know how to apply it to concepts connections.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{PN}{RGB}{97,189,64}
\definecolor{CFO}{RGB}{92,219,101}
\definecolor{DCO}{RGB}{255,131,211}
\definecolor{AN}{RGB}{72,163,235}
\definecolor{IQ}{RGB}{234,193,137} 
\definecolor{IQTx}{RGB}{255,173,45} 
\definecolor{IQRx}{RGB}{216,182,145}
\definecolor{IQFs}{RGB}{252,221,153}
\definecolor{IQFi}{RGB}{252,218,23}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, scale=0.8,
 every concept/.style={scale=.8, font=\bfseries, text=white},
 marca/.append style={general shadow={fill=black,shadow scale=1.07}},
 outer sep=1pt,
  ]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=red]
    node[concept, marca] {\bf Root}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=IQ] {
      node[concept, marca] {\bf A}
      [clockwise from=120]
        child [concept color=IQTx] {node[concept, marca] {A1}}
        child [concept color=IQRx] {node[concept, marca] {A2}}
        child [concept color=IQFs] {node[concept] {A3}}
        child [concept color=IQFi] {node[concept, marca] {A4}}}  
    child [concept color=DCO, grow=75, level distance=4.5cm] {node[concept] {B}}
    child [concept color=PN, grow=150, level distance=4.5cm] {node[concept] {C}} 
    child[concept color=CFO, grow=215, level distance=4.5cm] {node[concept, marca] {D}}
    child[concept color=AN, grow=290, level distance=4.5cm] {node[concept] {E}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]